# MATLAB: Undefined function or variable 'bayesreg'

Tags: matlab, modeling, bayesian

I want to use the bayesreg package within the MATLAB environment, which enables flexible Bayesian penalized regression modelling. I am following a paper, which details the software implementation within the MATLAB environment. I am using the exact instructions available in the paper but do not seem to get the code to work.

I have imported the table containing the data that I want to analyze. I then type the following code:

```
varnames=finale.Properties.VariableNames;
% count regression

X = finale{:,2:9}
y = finale{:,11}

[beta, beta0, retval] = bayesreg(X,y,'poisson','g','nsamples',1e5,'burnin',1e5,'thin',5,'displayor',true,'varnames',varnames(2:9),'display',true);
```

X and y are simply my dependent and independent variables, and all arguments of bayesreg are in agreement with the software implementation paper instructions.

I get the below error:

**Undefined function or variable 'bayesreg'.**

Could anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I didn't have the Neural Network toolbox installed, as well as another 1-2 packages. Installing those solved the issue.